# What is a trustworthy 2x4GB RAM for MacBook Pro 15" 2.4Mhz Core i5?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory, hardware-recommendation

I'm looking to upgrade memory from 4GB to 8GB on my MacBook Pro 15" 2.4Mhz Core i5.

I've been looking at [Mushkin 8GB RAM on NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820226015&Tpk=976644A), but it's been getting bad reviews lately for not working properly with MacBook Pro Core i7. I'm not sure if it still works OK with Core i5...

Is there a trusted 8GB(2x4) RAM upgrade for MacBook Pro 15" 2.4Mhz Core i5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I’ve always brought memory from [OWC](http://www.macsales.com/) with success.

Comment: You had good experience with OWC for a MacBook Pro? Their 8GB memory is about $25 cheaper than Crucial...

Comment: I brought memory three times. Powerbook 15’, Macbook Pro and later Mac Pro. Never complained or had any weird problems. At least that it was attributed to OWC’s memory. I brought there after reading other reviews. The guys have a name and it has worked so far. :)

Comment: Here is another vote for Other World Computing or OWC. I have been a customer of theirs for many years. If anything is defective they will replace it promptly. If the price goes down between when you place your order and when you receive your RAM, they will even refund the difference.

Answer (score 3):

I've always had good success with [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=7C0D2C4EA5CA7304), but I can't speak to your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

As long as this is branded stuff that went through testing, and not some chips that were sorted out / relabeled / rebranded, you usually don't have much issues with RAM these days.

However, RAM issues are still a major source of Macs behaving badly, so the most important  thing is to really check it.

No matter where and what you buy, make sure they take the RAM back if "Memtest OS X" fails during an extensive RAM test on your machine.

Now build in your new RAM, and run Memtest OS X (details i.e. at [OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/03/memtest-mac-ram-test/)).

The tests will need a couple of hours, and really put your RAM under stress. If all tests are running ok, you are fine, if not, send the RAM back.